# Broken Pipe Error while using Loading Text Data in Pytorch

Tags: python, text, deep-learning, nlp, pytorch

I'm trying to preprocess some text data but after creating a pytorch dataloader, and looping through to check if it is working, I get a Broken Pipe Error. However when trying again in Google Colab, the code works so I think it may be a problem with my setup.

(The Collate class is useless, I just haven't removed it yet.)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("imdb.csv")

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader

import spacy
spacy_eng = spacy.load("en")

class Vocabulary():
    def __init__(self, freq_threshold=4):
        self.word_to_index = {"<PAD>":0, "<SOS>":1, "<EOS>":2, "<UNK>":3}
        
        self.freq_threshold = freq_threshold
        self.max_length = 0
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.word_to_index)
    
    @staticmethod
    def tokenizer_eng(text):
        return [tok.text.lower() for tok in spacy_eng.tokenizer(text)]
    
    def build_vocabulary(self, sentence_list):
        frequencies = {}
        idx = 4
        
        longest_length = 0
        
        for sentence in sentence_list:
            if len(sentence) > longest_length:
                self.max_length = len(sentence)
                longest_length = self.max_length
                
            for word in self.tokenizer_eng(sentence):
                if word not in frequencies:
                    frequencies[word] = 1
                else:
                    frequencies[word] += 1
                
                if frequencies[word] == self.freq_threshold:
                    self.word_to_index[word] = idx
                    idx += 1
        
        self.max_length += 25
    
    def numericalize(self, text):
        tokenized_text = self.tokenizer_eng(text)
        
        vector_text = []
        
        for token in tokenized_text:
            if token in self.word_to_index:
                vector_text.append(self.word_to_index[token])
            else:
                vector_text.append(self.word_to_index["<UNK>"])
        
        vector_text.append(self.word_to_index["<EOS>"])
        
        pad_length = self.max_length - len(vector_text)
        for i in range(0, pad_length):
            vector_text.append(self.word_to_index["<PAD>"])
            
        return vector_text


class IMDBDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self):
        data = pd.read_csv("imdb.csv").to_numpy()
        
        self.target = []
        for data_point in data[:, 2]:
            if data_point == "neg":
                self.target.append(0)
            else:
                self.target.append(1)
                
        self.text = data[:, 4]

        self.vocab = Vocabulary()
        self.vocab.build_vocabulary(self.text)
    
    def __len__(self):
        return self.text.shape[0]
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        review = self.text[idx]
        
        vector_text = [self.vocab.word_to_index["<SOS>"]]
        vector_text += self.vocab.numericalize(review)
        
        target = self.target[idx]
        
        return torch.tensor(vector_text), torch.tensor(target)


class Collate:
    def __init__(self, pad_idx):
        self.pad_idx = pad_idx
    
    def __call__(self, batch):
        text = [item[0] for item in batch]
        text = nn.utils.rnn.pad_sequence(text, batch_first=False, padding_value=self.pad_idx)
        
        return text, batch[1]

def get_loader(batch_size=32, num_workers=4, shuffle=True, pin_memory=True):
    dataset = IMDBDataset()
    pad_idx = dataset.vocab.word_to_index["<PAD>"]
    
    loader = DataLoader(
        dataset=dataset,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        num_workers=num_workers,
        shuffle=shuffle,
        pin_memory=pin_memory,
        collate_fn=Collate(pad_idx=pad_idx) # Redundant now
    )
    
    return loader, dataset

train_dl, train_ds = get_loader()

for idx, (data, target) in  enumerate(train_dl):
    print(data.shape)
```

Comment: Hello, please provide a **minimal** reproducible example : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . Copypaste the error message here as well. And if it works on google colab but not on your local machine, then it's not unlikely that code is not at fault, but rather your local setup is, so you may want to describe it in the question

Answer (score 0):

Dunno why it worked, but by removing the get_loader() function and just getting the dataloader by itself, fixed this.

```
train_dl = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using

```
if __name__ == '__main__' and '__file__' in globals():
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using Windows. Pytorch's dataloader gives this error when you are setting `num_workers > 0`. So to fix this error, set `num_workers = 0` or call the dataloader under `if __name__ == "__main__:` (I can't explain you why the last one works).